# Generate combinations of values from rolling window in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, combinations, python-itertools

For every row in my dataframe, I need to create every combination of two values of column `a` *from a three-day sliding window ending at that row*. My dataframe is like this:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
                   index=[pd.Timestamp('20180101'),
                          pd.Timestamp('20180102'),
                          pd.Timestamp('20180103'),
                          pd.Timestamp('20180105'),
                          pd.Timestamp('20180106')])
```

Note that the time index is ragged (inconsistent intervals between rows). The combinations should come out to be:

```
row0: None
row1: [(1, 2)]
row2: [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
row4: [(3, 4)]
row5: [(4, 5)]
```

I can do this easily enough *without* the window, just use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate every combination of two elements of column `a` with:

```
import itertools as it
combos = it.combinations(df['a'], 2)
for c in combos:
    print(c)
# (1, 2)
# (1, 3)
# (1, 4)
# (1, 5)
# etc.
```

but I need the windowed version for my application. My best bet so far is to use [`df.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html). I can do simple things like summing the elements over a three day window with something like:

```
df.rolling('3d').sum()
# get [1, 3, 6, 7, 9] which we expect
```

but I can't seem to perform more complicated operations (or return more complicated types than real numbers from an operation) on the rolling window.

---

### Question

How do I use `df.rolling` to make combinations over my rolling window? Or is there some other tool to do this?

---

### Attempts

My thought so far is that there is some way to use `df.rolling` and `df.apply` along with `it.combinations` to generate iterators for each window in my dataframe, and then plug that iterator into a new column of my dataframe. Something like:

```
df.rolling('3d').apply(lambda x: it.combinations(x, 2))
```

which gives a `TypeError`:

> TypeError: must be real number, not itertools.combinations

because [`df.rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html) requires that its argument return a single real value, not an object, nor a list.

I also tried using `it.combinations` directly on the rolling window:

```
it.combinations(df.rolling('3d'), 2)
```

which gives:

> KeyError: 'Column not found: 0'

and if I select column `a` explicitly:

```
it.combinations(df.rolling('3d')['a'], 2)
```

I get:

> Exception: Column(s) a already selected

So is there maybe a way to define a function that I can call with `df.apply` that plugs the iterator over my rolling window into a new column for each row of my dataframe? Can I even operate on rows other than the current row in a function passed to `apply`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this is a hack, but it might be useful.

All we want to do is reuse df.rolling's windowing facilities.  We could try to look inside some non-public parts of the code, but instead let's just take advantage of the fact we can force a function call inside apply before we return a float:

```
In [28]: dummy = df.rolling("3d")["a"].apply((lambda x: print(x) or 0), raw=False)
2018-01-01    1.0
dtype: float64
2018-01-01    1.0
2018-01-02    2.0
dtype: float64
2018-01-01    1.0
2018-01-02    2.0
2018-01-03    3.0
dtype: float64
2018-01-03    3.0
2018-01-05    4.0
dtype: float64
2018-01-05    4.0
2018-01-06    5.0
dtype: float64
```

And so:

```
In [29]: roll_slices = []

In [30]: dummy = df.rolling("3d")["a"].apply((lambda x: roll_slices.append(list(combinations(x, 2))) or 0), raw=False)

In [31]: roll_slices
Out[31]: 
[[],
 [(1.0, 2.0)],
 [(1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 3.0), (2.0, 3.0)],
 [(3.0, 4.0)],
 [(4.0, 5.0)]]
```

After which you can do what you like.

Comment: WOW!  Appending to a list in side rolling apply.  Nice.  +1

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'`, I think because it is the [`pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html) method that is getting called, and not the [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method. Any ideas?

Comment: You're probably using an older version of pandas.  Does it work if you just drop the `raw=False`?  (I just got it to run in 0.19.2 after dropping it, which is the oldest version I have on hand, as well as 0.23.0, the one I'm currently using.)

Comment: Just a note (wasn't in the problem statement, but I thought I'd add it here), if I want only *unique* combinations, I can use your idea but define `roll_slices = set()` and then `df.rolling('3d')['a'].apply(lambda x: roll_slices.update(it.combinations(x, 2)) or 0)`. Cool idea!